# stubborn prolem with popular custom scrollbar

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

code updated : http://mawk3y.net/test/brand.php?id=12

the original jquery plugin is here http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html

```
$(".content1").mCustomScrollbar({
scrollButtons:{
enable:true
}
});
$("#contact_details").mCustomScrollbar({
scrollButtons:{
enable:true
}
});
```

.content1 is the div with the problem : custom scrollbar doesn't show up untill you resize the window or start firebug and contact_details is the div inside the first tab which is without any problem though both divs contain text only."

Comment: can you post the HTML or a jsfiddle (jsfiddle.net) link with all of the HTML and JavaScript pieces please?

Comment: uploading the whole site for testing it''s be alive in minutes

Comment: uploaded. http://mawk3y.net/tanami/brand.php?id=12 third tab

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your

```
$(window).load(function(){
```

is inside your

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
```

Remove the document ready function if your going to have images inside this div.  Otherwise Remove the window load function.  You won't need both.

Comment: no it's not the problem because i've moved the code outside document ready and the problem is still on (source code is inside document ready and i just copied it)

Comment: and when writing the code inside the document ready without window.load it doesn't work at all. I've updated code please check again.

Answer (score 0):

Your inline CSS for the scroll bar within `#content_11` has `display:none` set.

```
<div class="mCSB_scrollTools" style="position: absolute; display: none;"> ... </div>
```

When you re-size the page, the plug-in is overwriting that element, which makes it appear. By manually replacing `display: none` with `display: block;` in my browser, I can make the scroll bar appear (albeit in the wrong place).

Your functional div, `#contact_details` has `display: block` already.

```
<div class="mCSB_scrollTools" style="position: absolute; display: block;">...</div>
```

Comment: ok it's displaying with making it a block but not functioning

Comment: and when displaying the original scrollbar of mCustomScrollBox div by changing overflow to auto it doesn't function too