# mCustomScrollbar - scrollbar only appearing on F12 press (dev tools / Firebug) and not on hidden elements/divs

Tags: jquery, css, scrollbar, custom-component, mcustomscrollbar

Having a weird problem with mCustomScrollbar  - Similar problem here:

[stubborn prolem with popular custom scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489518/stubborn-prolem-with-popular-custom-scrollbar)

The scrollbar doesn't show until you re-size the window or hit F12 (tested on both IE9 and FF - so Developer and Firebug). As soon as you do either, the code kicks in. The elements are initially hidden, and shown either using .show() or .fadeIn()

CSS:

```
.info-text {
    width: 230px;
    height: 170px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p class = "info-text">
Lorem...
</p>
```

JS:

```
$(".info-text").mCustomScrollbar();
```

The JS is held within a `$(window).load(function(){...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. The reason that it wasn't firing was because I was trying to add the functionality onto a div that wasn't initially visible, and subsequently brought in using .fadeIn(). For some reason it doesn't like that. I had to use:

```
.mCustomScrollbar('update');
```

to bring in the scrollbar after the element was visible. So in my case it was:

```
$("#elementFadingIn").fadeIn(500, function() {

    $("#elementFadingIn .scrollableElement").mCustomScrollbar('update');

});
```

Then it worked.

Answer (score 5):

you could try ,at init time, to use the property

```
advanced:{  
    updateOnContentResize:true,   
    updateOnBrowserResize:true
  }
```

so you should have something similar to:

```
$(".info-text").mCustomScrollbar({
   advanced:{  
    updateOnContentResize:true,   
    updateOnBrowserResize:true   

  } 
});
```

Comment: Awesome hint! I had a similar problem and my scrollbars are now working! Thanks so much, dude!!!:)